# How do I make PHP output all error information programatically?

Tags: php

I can't change the php.ini for some reason,

how can I do it in code level?

Comment: If you have access to your php.ini, I would first try to find out why you can't change any values in there.

Comment: note that ini_set won't help with parse errors. `.htaccess` is another option where available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

- [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) — Sets the value of a configuration option

Example from Manual:

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}
```

but keep in mind your hosting service might have disabled programmatic setting of ini settings.

---

Also keep in mind that you have to have `error_reporting` enabled:

- [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) — Sets which PHP errors are reported

Example from Manual:

```
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: Isn't `error_reporting(-1);` enough ? Do I also set `display_errors` to `on`?

Comment: @user198729 error_reporting just sets what is reported, not if it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ini_set` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Specifically,

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'E_ALL');
```

should work

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel What's so ridiculous about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(-1); //Passing in the value -1 will show every possible error, even when new levels and constants are added in future PHP versions
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Doc available there:

- [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
- [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Another way (if your server supports it) is with an .htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting -1
```

Comment: *(tip)* Passing in the value `-1` will show every possible error, even when new levels and constants are added in future PHP versions.

Comment: I guess because it's bytewise and -1 equals to all flags raised?

Comment: because Rasmus said so http://twitter.com/rasmus/status/7448448829 ;) well, actually, it's also at the bottom of the manual page for `error_reporting`.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime configuration of error reporting can be finetuned with a number of functions, listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

But most directly related to your question, use error_reporting(E_ALL), and display_errors(1)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

From an .htaccess file:

```
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

6143 is the integer value of E_ALL, since apache won't understand "E_ALL"